# Dex file exceeded 64k after adding Google Play Services 9.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I was following the Firebase guide to adding FCM, and so I added the following dependencies to my app gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this one to my project gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

After this, I added the google-services.json from the Firebase console settings by downloading it and adding it to my app directory.

Now I'm getting this error:

*Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html*

If I follow the instructions and have my application to support multidex, my application crashes as soon as it launches.

Here is the error after adding multidex to my app:

```
    05-20 01:25:32.253 19812-19812/com.cryogenos.pearsonvisionlimousine W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 8723 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;05-20 01:25:32.253 19812-19812/com.cryogenos.pearsonvisionlimousine W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416b5e30)05-20 01:25:32.253 19812-19812/com.cryogenos.pearsonvisionlimousine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.cryogenos.pearsonvisionlimousine, PID: 19812java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$stringat com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzah.<init>
(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1609)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1574)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5643)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5206)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5883)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:688)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My phone's google play services is 9.0.0+. 
I have updated to the latest play services and the repository in SDK manager.

EDIT:

My app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cryogenos.pearsonvisionlimousine"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "2.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: why do u include all the play service libraries in ur project?

Comment: Because the instructions for adding Firebase Cloud messaging tell me to.

Comment: Hmmm it has its own dependency that is listed in guide Android dev website

Comment: Search for FGM google

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ i mean this, follow it

Comment: That is exactly what I'm following.

Comment: Use the multidex http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12402868. In any case you don't need to use this dependency: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible way to avoid `64k Dex error` is by including only those APIs which your app needs from Google Play Services.

> **[Selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)**
>   From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your build.gradle file:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
>   with these lines:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.0.0'
>   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.0'

**UPDATED**
Well I read the doc, which says

> Apps that rely on the Play Services SDK should always check the device for a compatible Google Play services APK before accessing Google Play services features

So you only need to check Google Play Service is available or not. And to do this you only need ***Google Actions, Base Client Library API***.

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0'`

Comment: Except, I don't know which one I'm suppose to add since Firebase instructions say to add the compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

Comment: @Cyogenos please share that instructions link.

Comment: This: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites and this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest

Comment: Thanks, this essentially solved the problem with dex.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  is firebase needs Google Play APK to be installed to use firebase features?  and however he has `firebase core` in gradle.

Answer (score 8):

as explained in [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) use **Selectively compiling APIs into your executable** which is best approach for you(***take it in first priority insted of Multi Dex***), because Multi-dex have some [**limitations**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) ***check before proceed.***

**Avoiding the 64K Limit - Proguard will help you**

> Before configuring your app to enable use of 64K or more method
> references, you should take steps to reduce the total number of
> references called by your app code, including methods defined by your
> app code or included libraries. The following strategies can help you
> avoid hitting the dex reference limit:
>
> **Review your app's direct and transitive dependencies** - Ensure any large library dependency you include in your app is used in a manner
> that outweighs the amount of code being added to the application. A
> common anti-pattern is to include a very large library because a few
> utility methods were useful. Reducing your app code dependencies can
> often help you avoid the dex reference limit.
>
> **Remove unused code with ProGuard** - Configure the ProGuard settings for your app to run ProGuard and ensure you have shrinking enabled for
> release builds. Enabling shrinking ensures you are not shipping unused
> code with your APKs.
>
> Using these techniques can help you avoid the
> build configuration changes required to enable more method references
> in your app. These steps can also decrease the size of your APKs,
> which is particularly important for markets where bandwidth costs are
> high.

***So, try to avoid Multi-Dex***

---

one more thing when you use `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` then you not need to use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` and `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'`. ***so remove v7 & v4 from build.gradle file***

Comment: Upvote for the hint about not needing appcompat libraries if you have the design library installed

Answer (score 0):

First check if the multidex has really worked, you can do that by renaming the apk file to zip and extracting it. There should 2 multiple classes.dex files.

Secondly, it can also happen if earlier to reduce the method you must have used proguard, so just comment the use of proguard and it should work.

Otherwise paste your exception here.

Comment: I have pasted my exception in the post.

Comment: I meant after doing above 2 steps !

Comment: What do you mean "comment the use of proguard"? How do I do this? Also I generated an apk and I only see one classes.dex file.

Comment: Then ur multidex is not working. Can u paste ur build.gradle

Comment: Added it to the original post

Comment: comment out this line. proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'    r  u building debug or release mode  ?

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong.

Checking [the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#set-up-firebase-and-the-fcm-sdk) you only need this dependency

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
```

So you can **remove** this dependency

```
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

**If it is not enough** and you have more than **65536 methods** you can use the [**multidex support**](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html).

Just add these lines in the `build.gradle`:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Also in your `Manifest` add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and override `attachBaseContext` method:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

If you are using a own `Application` class, change the parent class from `Application` to `MultiDexApplication`.