# Using Google PlusOne button dex

Tags: google-play-services, dex, google-plus-one

I want to use a Google Plus one button in my application. In gradle, I have

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

But since the library huge, I get the error:

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Is there an easy way using this, just include a smaller library instead of entire :play-services ?

I already looked at stackoverflow other answers to multidex enabling but my question is to do without it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dex file exceeded 64k after adding Google Play Services 9.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338398/dex-file-exceeded-64k-after-adding-google-play-services-9-0-0)

Comment: I am checking if there is an easy to do like just adding a smaller library as :      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'  instead of the whole     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
 library  and not doing multidex enabled

Answer (score 0):

apparently there is no way to solve it other than to enable multiDex